# кратное повторение загружаемого контента ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

на данный момент контент в ленту новостей подгружается ajax, функция срабатывает путем клика по кнопке onclick="" в конце документа.

Пытаюсь реализовать на сайте автоматическу подгрузку контента при прокрутке в конец документа, скрипт срабатывает но подгружает контент первый раз верно, потом с одним повтором, потом с 2умая повторами....

хотя при запуске функции через onclick="" работает корректно. 
Помогите пожалуйста

пример работы тут [ссылка](http://malinasport.ru/)!

```
var page = 1; //Счетчик загруженых данных
$(window).scroll(function() 
{
     if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) 
 {
      //Пользователь внизу страницы, подгружаем контент
    nextPage();  
  }
});


function nextPage() {
var nextPage = $('#ajax-next-page a').attr('href'); 
ShowLoading(""); 
if (nextPage !== undefined) 
{ 
$.ajax(
    { url: nextPage, success: function(data)

        {   $('#ajax-next-page').remove(); 
            $('#next-page').remove(); 
        HideLoading(""); 
            $('#dle-content').append($('#dle-content', data).html()); 
        } 
    }) 
}
else
 HideLoading("");
};
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Как тогда быть в данном случае? не могу решить эту загадку уже сутки....

Comment: @Малина, Например вынести код скрипта в отдельный файл и прицепить его в head

Answer (score 2):

Ваш Ajax запрос подгружает весь написанный выше скрипт, в котором у вас есть строка:

```
var page = 1;
```

Тем самым обнуляя счётчик.

При вызове Ajax запроса через событие onclick вы вызываете только функцию

```
nextPage();
```

Значение счётчика страницы, в этом случае, работает правильно.